# How to get variable value in extensionContext

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

How would I get the value of the result field into my TestReporter class?

```
@ExtendWith({TestReporter.class})
private TestClass{
   String result;

   @Test
   void testA(){
     //some action here
     result = some result;
   }
}
```

```
public class TestReporter implements BeforeAllCallback, BeforeTestExecutionCallback, AfterAllCallback,
       TestWatcher {
    private static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    private static ExtentReports extent;
    private static ExtentTest test;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
       //set up extent report
    }


   @Override
   public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
     //not possible, but desired
     test.pass(context.getElement.get("result"), MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("test"+count+".png").build());

   }

}
```

I have been researching ways to do this but not sure if what Im looking for is even possible or how to implement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TLDR;

Use reflection in the extension that has to implement an appropriate callback, e.g. `AfterEachCallback`. Grab the instance of the test class through `context.getRequiredTestInstance()`.

### Long Version

```
@ExtendWith(TestReporter.class)
public class TestClass {

    String result;

    @Test
    void testA() {
        result = "some result";
    }
}

class TestReporter implements AfterEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void afterEach(final ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Object testInstance = context.getRequiredTestInstance();

        Field resultField = testInstance.getClass().getDeclaredField("result");

        String resultValue = (String) resultField.get(testInstance);

        System.out.println("Value of result: " + resultValue);
    }
}
```

Mind that an `AfterAllContext` does NOT have access to the test instance because there is one instance per test method. Using `TestWatcher` instead of `AfterEachCallback` would also work.